# How to get only text from wordpress post content?

Tags: posts, images, content

I have been using wordpress for my projects. For my homepage of the site I need to display limited text from the post content and the content contains images as well. To display the 100 text i have used substr function of php. What happens here is that the text as well as image is dispalayed. I want to display only the text. Is there any way or plugin to do so?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

use  strip_tags + substr

```
substr( strip_tags( get_the_excerpt() ),0,235);
```

Comment: Thank you Satish .. Actually I know about strip_tags php function but did not think of using it :P. It worked for me..

Comment: Use `mb_substr()` to avoid broken UTF-8 characters.

Comment: problem is, that this will still contain stuff like [caption ... ][/caption]

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the loop, then use wp_trim_excerpt() function, which will return an extract of 55 words.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     // Your HTML code...
     <p><?php echo wp_trim_excerpt(); ?></p>
     // Go on with more HTML (if you want to)
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Otherwise, if you're not in the loop then try using the excerpt field that is set from the post edit screen.